# What is this sql injection attack and what should I check to see I am not vulnerable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I am escaping through PDO all my inputs.
From time to time I see in my logs the following attack:

```
1 AND 1=2 UNION SELECT 0x6461726b31636f6465,0x6461726b32636f6465,0x6461726b33636f6465,0x6461726b34636f6465,0x6461726b35636f6465,0x6461726b36636f6465,0x6461726b37636f6465,0x6461726b38636f6465,0x6461726b39636f6465,0x6461726b3130636f6465,0x6461726b3131636f6465
```

What does it look for?

Comment: Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly meant what you wrote. But that is not my question (how to be safe) raher I would like to understand what is going on there,